# Hash of array in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a hash of array. How do I access/print the entire array? Here is the code:

```
 my %data;    
 my @row = ("My", "Name", "is", "Anthony", "Gonzalves");
 print "@row";
 $data{'First'} = \@row;
 print "@data{'First'}";
```

The output of the above code is:
My Name is Anthony GonzalvesARRAY(0x7fa1a5831dc8).

Comment: `$data{'First'}` is a reference to an array. You want `print "@{ $data{'First'} }";`

Comment: Work through tutorial [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)   and cookbook [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@{}` to access a ref of a array:

```
%HoA=(
    flintstones =>["fred","barney"],
);

$HoA{teletubbies}=["tinky winky","dipsy","laa-laa","po"];

for $family (keys %HoA){
    print "$family: @{$HoA{$family}}\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
simpsons: homer Marge bart
teletubbies: tinky winky dipsy laa-laa po
```